# show total amount of orders on the top of a sonata admin list

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

After filtering for a particular criteria, display total of the sales transaction amounts on top of the page. This should be total of all the pages if pages are more than one.

Can someone guide me how to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We did it in the following manner and it is working like a charm

**Step 1 :** Added two methods in orderAdmin

```
public function getTemplate($name)
{
    if($name == 'list') {
        return 'AppBundle:OrderAdmin:list.html.twig';
    }

    return parent::getTemplate($name); stub
}

public function getSumOf($field)
{
    $datagrid = $this->getDatagrid();
    $datagrid->buildPager();
    $query = $datagrid->getQuery();

    $query->select('SUM( ' . $query->getRootAlias() . '.' . $field . ') as total');
    $query->setFirstResult(null);
    $query->setMaxResults(null);


    $result = $query->execute(array(), \Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_SINGLE_SCALAR);

    return $result;
}
```

**Step 2:** Created a template file list.html.twig

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list.html.twig' %}
{% block list_header %}
<div class="pull-right" style="margin-right: 10px;">
    <label for="{{ admin.uniqid }}_sum_of_orders" class="control-label">Grand Total: </label>
    <label class="control-label"> S$ {{ admin.getSumOf('orderAmount') }} </label>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: When using this solution it makes high number of queries.