# SonataAdminBundle how to sum values of a column in the list view

Tags: php, symfony, twig, sonata-admin, sonata

I've a Symfony 2.8 project where I'm using SonataAdminBundle for basic CRUD of working hours. In the main list view (defined with `configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)`) there's a column with hours value that I want to sum and show in the footer of the list's table.

What's the best way to achieve this? How can I access the collection shown from the Twig template in order to iterate over all elements and sum the right values?

Comment: duplicate. Answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37549253/816362

Answer (score 0):

> How can I access the collection shown from the Twig template in order to iterate over all elements and sum the right values?

If you're suggesting doing that in the template, I think you shouldn't, if you're suggesting doing that in the controller with php, I think you shouldn't either. I think you should get the DQL query corresponding to the list from the pager, clone it and modify it to add a call to the `SUM()` SQL function, the executing and inject the result in your template.