# Sonata Admin + show all items on list view (not per page)

Tags: php, symfony, pagination, sonata-admin, sonata

In the [Sonata Admin Bundle](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/index.html) you have a list view where you can add fields you want to show in your table.

At the bottom of the table you have the number of results and pagination. I like the pagination and items per page. But I would like to show ALL the items at the load of the page. So all the items are shown on the page but you can still choose to decrease the number of results per page.

[image]

The problem is I don't have a clue on how to do this. Can someone set me on my way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37537300/show-total-amount-of-orders-on-the-top-of-a-sonata-admin-list

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37537300/show-total-amount-of-orders-on-the-top-of-a-sonata-admin-list [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37537300/show-total-amount-of-orders-on-the-top-of-a-sonata-admin-list)

Answer (score 4):

In SonataAdmin 3.x to have all rows by default you need to do the following :

1 - Add _per_page = All to `$datagridValues` :

```
 protected $datagridValues = array(
    '_sort_order' => 'ASC',
    ...
    '_per_page' => 'All',
);
```

2 - Add All to $perPageOptions:

```
protected $perPageOptions = [16, 32, 64, 128, 192, 'All'];
```

3 - Set $maxPerPage to All:

```
protected $maxPerPage = 'All';
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class YourAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected $perPageOptions = [64, 128, 256, 'All'];

    protected $datagridValues = [
        '_per_page' => 'All',
    ];

    protected $maxPerPage = 'All';

    ...
}
```

If you find $maxPerPage variable as strange or redundant ask him @author Thomas Rabaix thomas.rabaix at sonata-project dot org

Comment: @nielsv this also load all the rows on the first load of the page

Answer (score 2):

Since Sonata 4.x, there are many updates, you need to use sonata functions and not attributs variables.

First, use the `configureDefaultSortValue(array &$sortValues)` function instead of `$datagridValues`

```
protected function configureDefaultSortValues(array &$sortValues): void
{
    $sortValues[DatagridInterface::PER_PAGE] = 'All';
}
```

Second, use the `getPerPageOptions():array` function instead of the `$perPageOptions` attribute

```
public function getPerPageOptions(): array
{
    $perPageOptions = parent::getPerPageOptions();
    $perPageOptions[] = 'All';

    return $perPageOptions;
}
```

You don't need to redefine the `$maxPerPage` variable (the function `getMaxPerPage(): int` is tagged as final anyway)

The documentation : https://symfony.com/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/current/reference/action_list.html#customizing-the-sort-order

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is possible to do.
You have in you `EntityAdmin` to

a) Define a list of possible "Results per page" values.

Now it is
`protected $perPageOptions = array(16, 32, 64, 128, 192);`

So the easiest solution could be just to put a new really big number, foe example

`protected $perPageOptions = array(16, 32, 64, 128, 192, 1000000);`

But if you want to make really "all", then you must do

`protected $perPageOptions = array(16, 32, 64, 128, 192, 'All');`

and then

2) redefine a method `EntityAdmin::buildDatagrid()` to process this `'All'` value of `$filterParameters['_per_page']`

Comment: Will this also load all the rows on the first load of the page?