# Sonata admin get all list items

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

is there any way to get all filtered items on Sonata Admin list view? An example if I fill some filters and get results, I can retrieve only one page results by this way:

`$datagrid = $this->admin->getDatagrid(); 
$datagrid->getResults()`

But if I need all results, how should I get them in list view Controller?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38901778/sonata-admin-show-all-items-on-list-view-not-per-page

Comment: Nope I don't need to show all results to user I'm fine with pagination, but in Controller I need to get all results and do extra stuff with them.

Comment: Hi! Did you find the answer. I'm having same issue.

Comment: @Ary I don't find a right way to do this, but I done this with this workaround https://pastebin.com/vBH6d27q hope it helps to you.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it like that

```html
$numPerPage = 100;
$datagrid = $this->admin->getDatagrid(); 
$datagrid->setValue('_per_page', '', $numPerPage);
$datagrid->getResults();
```

Hope it helps you